# I have a view issue in django the file is not working properly

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, backend

```
File "C:\Users\Zeeshan Alvi ( BUH )\Desktop\Python\Webitewithdjango\ebookbackend\ebookbackend\urls.py", line 26, in <module>       
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),  # Corrected URL pattern for login
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'myapp.views' has no attribute 'login_view'
```

I make my website fronted complete using HTML , CSS & Java Script . I also connect my contact page to my database and also get data , but I did a mistake a make a backend using a single file index.html only after I try to connect my login page with my database but it gives some error and that of my backend of contact page is also ruined and right now I try for many hours but cant fix the bug. Is there anyone to help me.

I need a person some to have a chat with him/her to discuss it .

Comment: The `views.py` module does not contain a view named `login_view`.  Why are you trying to import something that does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

It says that your **myapp** application in Django doesn't have **login_view** function in **views.py** file. Please check it, or There can be any Typo's in the Spelling of function name **login_view**.